# Creating a Batch file to add JPG to MP3 to create AVI for all the files in a folder

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I've got 20 jpg's and 20 mp3's. I'm trying to join them together to create an AVI. I want to do it all in one go. 
The files match together so that the first JPG in the folder matches up with the first audio. And the last jpg to the last mp3 and so forth.

The FFmpeg I've got to join them together is:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i picture1.jpg -i audio1.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest out.avi
```

I'm just struggling with creating a batch file to execute.
I'm using windows 10.

This is what I have so far:

@echo off
 set "sourcedir=C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\FFMPEG"
 set "outputdir=C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\FFMPEG\done"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for %%F in (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i Photo.jpg -i "%%F" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest "%outputdir%/%%F.avi"

POPD

pause

It creates an .avi in the folder done. However I'm looking to enable it to do It for multiple photos and audio but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you done some research into writing a batch loop? There are lots of examples available on the web.

Comment: See the [editing help](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to figure out how to properly format the commands in your question.